# Tkinter images not showing up when made through thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tk-toolkit

I have a script that is supposed to automatically change the picture on a button. When I refresh my frame manually the picture shows up normally, but when the script does it, it doesn't show up. When I hover over it, I get the error: `_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage" doesn't exist`. The same error usually occurs when you try to create a variable in a method, because the variable isn't bound to it's object. I do bind it here, but I think it happens because I'm using a thread to run that method. I can't figure out how to bind the variable when the method creating it is run by a thread. I tried not using the thread, but then I run into infinite recursion problems. Here's the important part of the code:

```
self.screens = []
for pc in master.server.clients:
    if pc['screen'] != '':
        self.screens.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(pc['screen']))
    else:
        self.screens.append(tk.PhotoImage(file='images/info-images/placeholder.png'))
row = 0
column = 0
for img in self.screens:
    btk.ImageButton(self.body.interior, image=img, width=270, height=180).grid(row=row, column=column, padx=10, pady=10)
    if column % 2 == 0 and column != 0:
        row += 1
        column = 0
    else:
        column += 1
thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_images, args=(master,))
thread.start()
```

And the method in the thread:

```
def update_images(self, master):
    time.sleep(master.server.INFO_COOLDOWN)
    computers = master.server.clients
    for i in range(len(computers)):
        if computers[i] != 'DISCONNECTED_USER':
            if computers[i]['screen'] != '':
                self.screens[i] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(computers[i]['screen'])
            else:
                self.screens[i] = tk.PhotoImage(file='images/info-images/placeholder.png')
```

Don't worry about the `btk.ImageButton`, or it's parent `self.body.interior`, they're custom widgets and they work just fine.

Comment: I don't see anything about this snippet that would cause this. Besides the unbound object the other common cause of this error is using `Tk()` more than once in your code. If that's not the case you'll have to show a [mcve] to get help.

Comment: I do note you seem to be starting a thread for every image in self.screens, which seems unintentional.

Comment: Oh the indents were messed up for some reason when copying. It's not like that in code. And Tk() is there only once. I'll work on the minimal reproducible example now.

Comment: Are you confident that the if statements in your thread are evaluating such that the image will change?

Comment: In the function, you reassign `self.screens[i]` to new instance of either `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` or `tk.PhotoImage()` but without reconfigure the `image` option of those buttons to these instances. As there is nothing references to the old instances of `PhotoImage()`, they are garbage collected.  Therefore the images of the buttons disappear.

Comment: I tried doing that, but the same thing happens

Comment: When I run `update_images(master)` manually (by button or in `__init__`) it works fine. That's why I think it's the thread causing it

Comment: always put full error message (startingat word "Traceback") in question (notcomment) as text (not screnshot). Thre are other useful information.

Comment: as I know `tkinter` is **not** `thread safe` and widgets should be used only in main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was that the image wasn't bound to an object, hence was garbage collected and empty.